# No module named xlsxwriter error while writing pandas df to excel

Tags: python, pandas

While writing the pandas code that writes *dataframe* to Excel.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I am getting this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1934, in __init__
import xlsxwriter
ImportError: No module named xlsxwriter
```

Do I need to import **xlsxwriter** module explicitly in the python file?

Comment: Yes. You need to install it separately using pip install xlsxwriter

Comment: Please fix formatting in your question (indentation and parethesis).

Comment: @dzang updated and fixed formatting

Comment: @AmirhosImani: Explicit import should not be necessary, but it needs to be installed properly (--> manually).

Comment: @albert correct. I also meant you need to install it - no need to explicitly import in your script

Comment: Maybe anyone of you can write it as an answer that helps python newcomers like me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Install the missing module `xlsxwriter` manually by running

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

After the module is installed properly, you do not need to import in manually since it will be imported as an dependency of `pandas`.

---

*Remark: Summarizing the answer from the comments given below the question as discussed [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/343031)*

Answer (score 2):

always first check the # pip list, where you can see the list of packages installed on system.

now be sure >>>> pip install XlssWriter (case sensitive)

next go to your IDE >> just try

#import xlsxwriter(no case sensitive).

here is the sample script for your reference:

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

workbook.close()
```