# If pandas uses xlsxwriter why do I have to install it when I want to use it directly?

Tags: pandas, pip, xlsxwriter

Why do I have to install `xlsxwriter` with `pip3` if `pandas` [uses it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858614/is-there-a-way-of-writing-a-formula-to-the-xlsx-file-just-with-pandas-i-e-wit/68860091#68860091) and I have `pandas` already installed?
Does `pandas` use only small part of it its dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, xlswriter is an `optional dependency` to pandas as in pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/install.html#optional-dependencies).  Therefore, it is not installed automatically with pandas because it is not a necessary dependency. Also, you should know that xlsxwriter module is installed separately to write worksheets in an Excel 2007+ XLSX file. If this module is not installed before, pandas could not work and arise an error as you can see in this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280131/no-module-named-xlsxwriter-error-while-writing-pandas-df-to-excel/55280686).

Finally, we do not need sometimes to install xlsxwriter manually. For instance, xlsxwriter is installed `automatically with Anaconda` as documented [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/excel/).